# Angular JS : No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, web-services, jakarta-ee, cors

I am trying to create a webservice. I am using AngularJS in client side and Java for webservice. This is my client side code

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8010/something';
    var data = {
            "departmentID":$scope.departmentID ,
            "departmentName":$scope.departmentName,
        };
    var config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'Application/JSON',
        },
        withCredentials : true
    };
    $http.put(url,data).success(
        function(data, status, headers, config){
            alert("success :"+data);
        }).error(
        function(data, status, headers, config){
            alert("Failure :"+data);
        }       
    );
```

This is my server side code

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response add(final Department department) {
    try {
        DepartmentRelation.addDepartment(department);
        return Response.status(Status.OK).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT").header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true).build();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT").build();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT").build();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error - "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access." While I try using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser will do a preflight request using the OPTIONS method to check access to the resource. You need to implement a method in your JAX-RS backend responding to OPTIONS requests with CORS headers (as you already do in the "add" method).

```
@OPTIONS
public Response options() {
    return Response
            .status(Response.Status.OK)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",true)
            .build();
}
```